# Check duplicate data in database using Django

Tags: python, html, django, flatpickr

I have a problem which I want to check if data is duplicate based on name and date_travel, let say I add an item name Lebron James and choose multiple date `flatpickr` like `24-08-2023, 25-08-2023` and the expected result should return a `JsonResponse` says Duplicate date travel since In the image below the date 24-08-2023 already exist under the name of Lebron james but my problem it always return to else statement evein it has duplicate travel, hope someone helps me thanks in advance

[image]

**Here's what I've Tried** I've plan to split and used loop in every date and return in if existed/duplicate in database but it won't work

```
@csrf_exempt
def item_add(request):
    employeename = request.POST.get('EmployeeName')
    travel_date = request.POST.get('DateTravel')

    # Split the date string into individual dates
    individual_dates = travel_date.split(',')

    for date in individual_dates:
        cleaned_date = date.strip()
 
        
        query = """
            SELECT date_travel FROM tev_incoming
            WHERE name = %s
            AND date_travel LIKE %s;
        """

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query, [employeename, cleaned_date])
            results = cursor.fetchall()
             
        if results:
            return JsonResponse({'data': 'error', 'Duplcate date travel':results})
        
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'data': 'success', 'message': "Unique travel and name"})
```

**Html input**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="DateTravel" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="dateField"/>
```

**script**

```
 $('#dateField').flatpickr({
     mode: 'multiple',
     allowInput: true,
     dateFormat: 'd-m-Y',
     locale: {
        firstDayOfWeek': 1 // start week on Monday
       },
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the query:

from

```
query = """
        SELECT date_travel FROM tev_incoming
        WHERE name = %s
        AND date_travel LIKE %s;
    """
```

to

```
query = """
        SELECT date_travel FROM tev_incoming
        WHERE name = %s
        AND date_travel LIKE %%%s%%;
    """
```

so now, it would match the date anywhere in the string instead for searching for it from the left only.

Hope this would help.

Comment: If I tried that , it will have an error says `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` under the line `individual_dates = travel_date.split(',')`   and I dunno why

Comment: I think the problem is in my query I tried to compare it to normal query to navicat and it works fine but if I run and print it in django it doesn't get the result like querying in navicat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the location of the else statement, it will only go over the first date in individual_dates and depending on that go to the if or else statement. If you move the else statement to after the for loop it will work because it goes through all dates before coming to the conclusion that the date is unique.

```
@csrf_exempt
def item_add(request):
    employeename = request.POST.get('EmployeeName')
    travel_date = request.POST.get('DateTravel')

    # Split the date string into individual dates
    individual_dates = travel_date.split(',')

    for date in individual_dates:
        cleaned_date = date.strip()
 
        
        query = """
            SELECT date_travel FROM tev_incoming
            WHERE name = %s
            AND date_travel LIKE %s;
        """

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query, [employeename, cleaned_date])
            results = cursor.fetchall()
             
        if results:
            return JsonResponse({'data': 'error', 'Duplcate date travel':results})
        
    return JsonResponse({'data': 'success', 'message': "Unique travel and name"})
```

Comment: I done that before I put if else statement under for loop, but the result , it will return duplicate if there's EXACT exists in database let say I have data `24-08-2023` in database and when I choose another one `24-08-2023` it will duplicate, but if I choose unique that never existed exact value let say `24-08-2023,11-08-2023` it will not duplicate even `24-08-2023` already existed

Comment: I think the problem is in my query I tried to compare it to normal query to navicat and it works fine but if I run and print it in django it doesn't get the result like querying in navicat